# "lxc-create: lxc-helpers-bullseye: utils.c: get_template_path: 898 No such file or directory - bad template: debian" error on Forgejo actions

Tags: git, containers, lxc

I have a Forgejo server and I'm trying to setup the Forgejo runner to execute actions. The "Set up job" script worked before, but I don't know why, it's not working now. Here's all the log:

```
runner(version:v3.0.0) received task 31 of job 27, be triggered by event: push
workflow prepared
evaluating expression 'github.ref == 'refs/heads/code''
expression 'github.ref == 'refs/heads/code'' evaluated to 'true'
++ dirname /root/.cache/act/90b5b690eeb504de/act/workflow/start-lxc.sh
+ source /root/.cache/act/90b5b690eeb504de/act/workflow/lxc-helpers-lib.sh
++ export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
++ DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
++++ dirname /root/.cache/act/90b5b690eeb504de/act/workflow/lxc-helpers-lib.sh
+++ cd /root/.cache/act/90b5b690eeb504de/act/workflow
+++ pwd
++ LXC_SELF_DIR=/root/.cache/act/90b5b690eeb504de/act/workflow
++ LXC_BIN=/usr/local/bin
++ :
++ : bookworm
++ : /home
++ : false
++ source /etc/os-release
+++ NAME='Fedora Linux'
+++ VERSION='37 (Workstation Edition)'
+++ ID=fedora
+++ VERSION_ID=37
+++ VERSION_CODENAME=
+++ PLATFORM_ID=platform:f37
+++ PRETTY_NAME='Fedora Linux 37 (Workstation Edition)'
+++ ANSI_COLOR='0;38;2;60;110;180'
+++ LOGO=fedora-logo-icon
+++ CPE_NAME=cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:37
+++ DEFAULT_HOSTNAME=fedora
+++ HOME_URL=https://fedoraproject.org/
+++ DOCUMENTATION_URL=https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f37/system-administrators-guide/
+++ SUPPORT_URL=https://ask.fedoraproject.org/
+++ BUG_REPORT_URL=https://bugzilla.redhat.com/
+++ REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT=Fedora
+++ REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=37
+++ REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT=Fedora
+++ REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=37
+++ SUPPORT_END=2023-11-14
+++ VARIANT='Workstation Edition'
+++ VARIANT_ID=workstation
+ LXC_CONTAINER_RELEASE=bullseye
+ lxc_prepare_environment
+ lxc_maybe_sudo
++ id -u
+ test 0 '!=' 0
++ which lxc-create
+ build_template_act
++ template_act
+++ lxc_template_release
+++ echo lxc-helpers-bullseye
++ echo lxc-helpers-bullseye-act
+ local name=lxc-helpers-bullseye-act
+ lxc_exists lxc-helpers-bullseye-act
+ local name=lxc-helpers-bullseye-act
++ lxc-ls '--filter=^lxc-helpers-bullseye-act$'
+ test ''
++ lxc_template_release
++ echo lxc-helpers-bullseye
+ lxc_build_template lxc-helpers-bullseye lxc-helpers-bullseye-act
+ local name=lxc-helpers-bullseye
+ local newname=lxc-helpers-bullseye-act
+ lxc_exists lxc-helpers-bullseye-act
+ local name=lxc-helpers-bullseye-act
++ lxc-ls '--filter=^lxc-helpers-bullseye-act$'
+ test ''
++ lxc_template_release
++ echo lxc-helpers-bullseye
+ test lxc-helpers-bullseye = lxc-helpers-bullseye
+ lxc_build_template_release
++ lxc_template_release
++ echo lxc-helpers-bullseye
+ local name=lxc-helpers-bullseye
+ lxc_exists lxc-helpers-bullseye
+ local name=lxc-helpers-bullseye
++ lxc-ls '--filter=^lxc-helpers-bullseye$'
+ test ''
++ lxc_root lxc-helpers-bullseye
++ local name=lxc-helpers-bullseye
++ echo /var/lib/lxc/lxc-helpers-bullseye/rootfs
+ local root=/var/lib/lxc/lxc-helpers-bullseye/rootfs
+ local packages=sudo,git,python3
+ lxc-create --name lxc-helpers-bullseye --template debian -- --release=bullseye --packages=sudo,git,python3
lxc-create: lxc-helpers-bullseye: utils.c: get_template_path: 898 No such file or directory - bad template: debian
lxc-create: lxc-helpers-bullseye: lxccontainer.c: __lxcapi_create: 1798 Template "debian" not found
lxc-create: lxc-helpers-bullseye: tools/lxc_create.c: main: 317 Failed to create container lxc-helpers-bullseye
RUN exit status 1
```

The same action successfully completed the "Set up job" phase before I even installed lxc, so I don't understand why is now throwing this error. I tried installing `lxc` and `lxc-templates` and creating a Debian container but there is no way to make the error go away.

Here's the action I'm trying to use right now:

```yaml
# On every push this script is executed
on: push
name: Build and deploy GH Pages
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/code'
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.0.0
      - name: build_and_deploy
        run: echo hi
```

Can someone help me, please?